# make function sync node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the problem that the file does not yet exist before it is read out. As a result, I keep getting the error message `no such File`
.
To the best of my knowledge `fs.writeFileSync();` should solve that ...?

function in modul:

```
setup: function(server, RAM, client, message) {
    const dc = require("../libs/dcTools.js");
    const db = require('../libs/dbTools.js');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const channel = dc.getChannel(message, server.dashboard.channel);
    const dashboard = this.create(server, RAM, client);
    channel.send(dashboard).then(msg => {
      //that is the line ↓
fs.writeFileSync(`./RAM/${server.id}/dsbdmsgid.txt`, msg.id);
      console.log('done');
    });
//and this line produces the error ↓
    const msg = fs.readFileSync(`./RAM/${server.id}/dsbdmsgid.txt`, 'utf8');
    return msg;
  },
```

Function that calls the function:

```
execute(server, message) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const db = require('../../libs/dbTools.js');
    const dashboard = require('../../modules/dashboard.js');
    if (args[0] == "setup") {
      server.dashboard.channel = message.channel.id;
//function ↓
    server.dashboard.msg = dashboard.setup(server, message);
      console.log('ready');
      server.dashboard.mod = true;
      db.updateServer(server);
    } else if (args[0] == "off") {
      server.dashboard.mod = false;
      db.updateServer(server);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `then` handler does not run synchronously, so the entire `setup` function needs to be made `async` to fix this.

Comment: Why  are you trying to write the file, then read the file?  Don't you already have the data that you just wrote to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setup` function needs to be async Make the following changes to your function declaration:

```
setup: async function(server, RAM, client, message) {
    const dc = require("../libs/dcTools.js");
    const db = require('../libs/dbTools.js');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const channel = dc.getChannel(message, server.dashboard.channel);
    const dashboard = this.create(server, RAM, client);
    channel.send(dashboard).then(msg => {
      //that is the line ↓
    fs.writeFileSync(`./RAM/${server.id}/dsbdmsgid.txt`, msg.id);
      console.log('done');
    });
     //and this line produces the error ↓
    const msg = fs.readFileSync(`./RAM/${server.id}/dsbdmsgid.txt`, 'utf8');
    return msg;
  }
```

Now to call that function:

```
dashboard.setup(server, message).then((msg) => {
    // Use the returned value of msg
})
```

This should work, but I recommend using `fs.readFile` instead of `fs.readFileSync` since it will hold up the single thread loop while I/O is being performed and other process cannot continue until it's done.

Comment: If you're recommending `fs.readFile()` and `fs.writeFile()` (which is the right way to program a server), then why doesn't your answer show how to do it the right way?

Comment: I wanted to make minimum changes to make the code work, which it will.  But my recommendation is for their consideration only and I believe they can figure out how to use it.

Comment: Where did the `channel.send()` go that was in the OP's question?  That appears to be asynchronous and is the source of the original problem.  So, it doesn't seem like you really solved anything.  Plus you say to call `dashboard.setup(...).then()`, but your setup function doesn't return a promise so that calling convention won't work at all.  I have no idea why the OP accepted this answer because it will not work as proposed.